# Using MKL to solve a non-linear system of equations with an objective function stored in another module

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran, intel-mkl, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to use the MKL trust region algorithm to solve a nonlinear system of equations in a Fortran program. I started from the example provided online (ex_nlsqp_f90_x.f90 https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/501498) and everything works correctly. Now, because I have to use this in a much bigger program, I need the user defined objective function to be loaded from a separate module. Hence, I split the example into 2 separate files, but I'm not able to make it compile correctly.

So here is the code for module which contains user defined data structure and the objective function

```
module modFun
implicit none
private
public my_data, extended_powell

type :: my_data
      integer a
      integer sum
end type my_data


contains

subroutine extended_powell (m, n, x, f, user_data)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: m, n
    real*8 , intent(in) :: x(n)
    real*8, intent(out) :: f(m)
    type(my_data) :: user_data
    integer i

    user_data%sum = user_data%sum + user_data%a
    do i = 1, n/4
        f(4*(i-1)+1) = x(4*(i-1)+1) + 10.0 * x(4*(i-1)+2)
        f(4*(i-1)+2) = 2.2360679774998 * (x(4*(i-1)+3) - x(4*(i-1)+4))
        f(4*(i-1)+3) = ( x(4*(i-1)+2) - 2.0 * x(4*(i-1)+3) )**2
        f(4*(i-1)+4) = 3.1622776601684 * (x(4*(i-1)+1) - x(4*(i-1)+4))**2
    end do
end subroutine extended_powell

end module modFun
```

and here the portion of the main program calling it

```
    include 'mkl_rci.f90'
program EXAMPLE_EX_NLSQP_F90_X
    use MKL_RCI
    use MKL_RCI_type
    use modFun

!   user's objective function
!   n - number of function variables
!   m - dimension of function value
    integer n, m
    parameter (n = 4)
    parameter (m = 4)
!   precisions for stop-criteria (see manual for more details)
    real*8 eps(6)
    real*8 x(n)
    real*8 fjac(m*n)
!   number of iterations
    integer fun

!   Additional users data
    type(my_data) :: m_data

    m_data%a = 1
    m_data%sum = 0
    rs = 0.0


   fun =  djacobix(extended_powell,n,m,fjac,x,eps(1),%val(loc(m_data)))

end program EXAMPLE_EX_NLSQP_F90_X
```

Also djacobix code

```
  INTERFACE
    INTEGER FUNCTION DJACOBIX(fcn, n, m, fjac, x, eps, user_data)
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN)   :: n
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN)   :: m
    DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(IN)      :: eps
    DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(IN), DIMENSION(*)     :: x
    DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(OUT), DIMENSION(m, *) :: fjac
    INTEGER(C_INTPTR_T)   :: user_data
    INTERFACE
        SUBROUTINE fcn(m, n, x, f, user_data)
            USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING
            INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: n
            INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: m
            DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(IN), DIMENSION(*) :: x
            DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(OUT), DIMENSION(*) :: f
            INTEGER(C_INTPTR_T), INTENT(IN) :: user_data
        END SUBROUTINE
    END INTERFACE
    END FUNCTION
  END INTERFACE
```

When i compile the following errors are generated:

```
mpiifort  -g -t -mkl  -I/apps/rhel6/intel/composer_xe_2015.3.187/mkl/include/intel64/lp64 -c modFun.f90
mpiifort  -g -t -mkl  -I/apps/rhel6/intel/composer_xe_2015.3.187/mkl/include/intel64/lp64 -c main.f90
main.f90(30): error #7065: The characteristics of dummy argument 5 of the associated actual procedure differ from the characteristics of dummy argument 5 of the dummy procedure.   [EXTENDED_POWELL]
   fun =  djacobix(extended_powell,n,m,fjac,x,eps(1),%val(loc(m_data)))
-------------------^
```

I have the feeling I have to create an interface to override the check on the m_data, but I can't figure out where and how.  Can anyone help me with this problem providing a working example?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43159202/accessing-variable-in-main-program-from-external-subroutine#comment73394501_43159202

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I tried what is suggested in this post (remove external declaration). It improves the situation but still I get the error :ex_nlsqp_f90_x_M.f90(170): error #7065: The characteristics of dummy argument 5 of the associated actual procedure differ from the characteristics of dummy argument 5 of the dummy procedure.   [EXTENDED_POWELL]. I also update the code on the te main post

Comment: You haven't shown us the code for `djacobix` which makes it kind of difficult to debug it.  But a wild guess is that you have been careless in matching the arguments when you call the function to those expected, maybe argument, oh, perhaps the 5th one, fails to match in rank/kind/type ?  For anything more like help, reduce your code to an [mcve] and post that.  Debugging the kind of pseudo-code you've posted is a fruitless exercise.

Comment: OK, I think I did some order and I reduced everything to the minimal. Also I found the code defining djacobix. Main topic updated.

Comment: `extended_powell`'s argument `user_data` is declared to be `type(my_data)`, but the interface of the subroutine in `DJACOBIX` has it as `INTEGER(C_INTPTR_T), INTENT(IN)`.  That's a mismatch you'll need to resolve.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try to think something about it. Take in mind that I have no control at all on subroutine djacobix, which is part of mkl. Hence I need to work on my objective function

Comment: Does replacing all the lines like `INTEGER(C_INTPTR_T) [, INTENT(IN)] :: user_data` in mkl_rci.f90 to `type(*) :: user_data` work (after copying mkl_rci.f90 to a local directory)? It seems to work on my linux box (with ifort-16).

Comment: @roygvib, thanks for the proposed solution, but modifying the mkl interface file is something that I don't want to do because that will make difficult to port on other machines. ut this may be an idea to submit directly at intel people to solve this issue without any workaround.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the reason is that the function `djacobix`  passes the pointer instead of the true value of variable `user_data`.
You can check the manual at https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/nonlinear-optimization-problem-solvers/jacobian-matrix-calculation-routines/jacobix.html where a sentence shows that "**You need to declare fcn as extern in the calling program.**"

Comment: There is no point declaring `fcn` external if there is an explicit interface available. It would actually be an error.

Comment: I think they 'known' this bug and that's why they state in the manual that you need to declare `fcn` as external function. Since compiler will not check the interface of external function, this step will 'jump over' this bug.

Comment: Note that the advice is for the C language, not for Fortran.